# Typo3 backend loads the frontend template

Tags: typo3

I copied my own build extension to a new Typo3 installation but now the backend template is not generated correctly anymore. In the "old" installation it is still working. The extension has a configuration menu in the backend that uses the list template. It should load the following template:

```
/ext/resources/backend/customers/list.html
```

But the extension loads the following instead:

```
/ext/resources/customers/list.html
```

In the ext_tables.php it is registered as follow:

```
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {

    /**
     * Registers a Backend Module
     */
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
        'MTR.' . $_EXTKEY,
        'user',  // Make module a submodule of 'user'
        'mtcus',    // Submodule key
        '',                     // Position
        array(
            'Customers' => 'list',
        ),
        array(
            'access' => 'user,group',
            'icon'   => 'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/ext_icon.gif',
            'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_mtcus.xlf',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: The problem is caused by an empty sys_template table in the datebase as the backend css is loaded from there.

Comment: I've the same issue but removing the existing empty sys_template not fixed my issue. :(

Answer (score 1):

After so much of investigation and reference I could able to find the issue with the plugin. When I created back-end module with Extension Builder the default TS configurations where created like. For example consider the extension key is **testextension** and the BE Module key is **custommodulebe** in TS file the module template path was registered like.

**IN constants.txt file**

```
module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe {
    view {
        # cat=module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (BE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        # cat=module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (BE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        # cat=module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (BE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =
    }
}
```

**IN setup.txt**

```
module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension_custommodulebe.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

> Fix was we only need to define the extension key in this module
>   configuration.

**Corrected Solution**
**constants.txt**

```
module.tx_testextension {
    view {
        # cat=module.tx_testextension/file; type=string; label=Path to template root (BE)
        templateRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Templates/
        # cat=module.tx_testextension/file; type=string; label=Path to template partials (BE)
        partialRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Partials/
        # cat=module.tx_testextension/file; type=string; label=Path to template layouts (BE)
        layoutRootPath = EXT:testextension/Resources/Private/Backend/Layouts/
    }
    persistence {
        # cat=module.tx_testextension//a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
        storagePid =
    }
}
```

**setup.txt**

```
 # Module configuration
module.tx_testextension {
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$module.tx_testextension.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$module.tx_testextension.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the static TypoScript template of your Extension.

[image: Here is a visual Example]